# Autorest fails to generate anything, and no error

Tags: azure, npm, swagger, openapi, autorest

I am trying the petshop client generation example on [github](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/docs/generating-a-client.md) and autorest just exits without creating anything or throwing any errors. Autorest behaves like I did not pass any arguments. Attached is a screenshot of my powershell execution.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I got it to work by manually downloading the AutoRest nuget package and running the same command with the executable from the package.

Comment: I reformatted the drive and reinstalled everything and that fixed the issue. I have no idea what was causing it though. I opened I ticket on GitHub for it, but I closed the issue once I was no longer able to reproduce it. 
https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2686 You should open a new one and reference mine, so they know multiple people are seeing this.

Answer (score 3):

For me what finally worked was:

1. Install the latest `Node` from https://nodejs.org/
2. Go to `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm` and delete the 2 `autorest` files there if you have them.
3. Open a `Command Prompt` (type `cmd` in the `address` of any `Windows folder`)
4. In the `Command Prompt` type this command:

   `npm cache clean -f`
5. Now, also in the same `Command Prompt`, type this command:

   `npm install autorest -g`

You should now be able to generate your client.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing your same command but add --verbose at the end to tell autorest to print out any errors.
I was experiencing the same problem and what worked for me was creating the following readme.yml file and simply running the command

```
autorest readme.yml
```

With those two things (readme.yml and the command) I was able to generate the code in csharp without any issues.

Image of Readme.yml for csharp code generation:

[image]

Comment: there is also the `--debug` option that actually shows what it does. For me it says _emitting file foo_, but doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This [answer on GitHub repo of Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2749), suggest that you execute

```
autorest --reset
```

after updating.  It removes older plugins of Autorest.  I had the same problem (without updating Autorest) and it has solved after that.